# Not able to echo the variable which is fetched in a function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I got two files name func.inc.php and profile.php 
I'm trying to fetch the data from the mysql by creating a function get_data($id) in func.inc.php and display in the profile page(profile.php).But the data is not displaying.

<-- func.inc.php file -->

```
<?php session_start();
function  get_data($id){
$query_in="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id ='$id'";
$query=mysql_query($query_in);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $name=$row['name'];
    $book=$row['book'];
    $mobile=$row['mobile'];
    $computer=$row['computer'];
}

} 
?>
```

<-- profile.php -->

```
<? 
include'func.inc.php';
echo "Name: ".$name;
echo "Book: ".$book;?>
```

Comment: Your function is not returning anything

Comment: I'm curious why you're taking a stab at doing it this way, which is akin to trying to rub two sticks together really quickly in the hopes of making fire, instead of using a proper framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) or [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) to give you a foundation to build on.

Comment: @tabman you are right, i just realized. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't mean sound so critical, but doing it by hand is *hard*. I don't miss the late 1990s when you had no option but to do it this way. Those days are thankfully over.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right but the site i'm building is just for hobby so was not using any framework. But after you said i googled about the frameworks.I will try learning these framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should return some value then only the values from the function will be got

```
   function  get_data($id){
    $query_in= sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id ='%d'", mysql_real_escape_string($id));
    $query=mysql_query($query_in);
    $result = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $result[]['name'] = $row['name'];
    }
    return $result;
    }
```

<-- profile.php -->

```
$values = get_data($id);

print_R($values);
```

Comment: Please, **please**, add `mysql_real_escape_string` to this to patch the [gigantic SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Or use mysqli or PDO. Its better

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the id from the function call that is: here you should call like this:

```
$values = get_data($id);

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($values)){
 echo $name=$row['name']."<br>";
 echo $book=$row['book']."<br>";
 echo $mobile=$row['mobile']."<br>";
 echo $computer=$row['computer']."<br>";
}
```

in func.inc.php use this code:

```
function  get_data($id){
  $query_in="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id ='$id'";
  $query=mysql_query($query_in);
  return $query;
}
```